# Syntax for QspinBox connection

Tags: qt5

For QPushButton named "pushButtonShow" we can create a slot with this syntax and we do not need  to explicitly create the connect expression

```
void on_pushButtonShow_clicked();
```

what would be the similar syntax for QSpinBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When designing Qt Widget forms I recommend you to use Qt Form editor in Qt Designer or Qt Creator. In this editor you can simply right click the selected object, open context menu and choose `Go to slot`, that will create C++ slot in your selected form class.

[image: Go to slot]

Alternatively, the syntax is always the same, put in slots following

`void on_<objectName>_<signalName>(<signal arguments>);`